# Why is my multi-threaded application being paused?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify, thread-synchronization

My multi-threaded application has a main class that creates multiple threads. The main class will wait after it has started some threads. The runnable class I created will get a file list, get a file, and remove a file by calling a web service. After the thread is done it will notify the main class to run again. My problem is it works for a while but possibly after an hour or so it will get to the bottom of the run method from the output I see in the log and that is it. The Java process is still running but it does not do anything based on what I am looking at in the log.

Main class methods:

Main method

```
while (true) {

    // Removed the code here, it was just calling a web service to get a list of companies

    // Removed code here was creating the threads and calling the start method for threads

    mainClassInstance.waitMainClass();
}

public final synchronized void waitMainClass() throws Exception {
//        synchronized (this) {
           this.wait();
//        }  
}

public final synchronized void notifyMainClass() throws Exception {
//        synchronized (this) {
           this.notify();
//        }  
}
```

I originally did the synchronization on the instance but changed it to the method. Also no errors are being recorded in the web service log or client log. My assumption is I did the wait and notify wrong or I am missing some piece of information.

Runnable Thread Code:

At the end of the run method

```
// This is a class member variable in the runnable thread class
mainClassInstance.notifyMainClass();
```

The reason I did a wait and notify process because I do not want the main class to run unless there is a need to create another thread.

The purpose of the main class is to spawn threads. The class has an infinite loop to run forever creating and finishing threads.

**Purpose of the infinite loop is for continually updating the company list.**

Comment: Have you added any sort of a log to find out what's going on?

Comment: Note that the notify only works if there's a thread waiting.  If your main thread has not quite gotten to the wait, the notify will fall on the ground.

Comment: You might do better with a semaphore.

Comment: Do you have a reason for using wait/notify? (e.g school project) or is this used in a product?  You would be better using a high-level synchronization method than "raw" wait/notify (which is hard to get right)

Comment: What is "this"? Are you trying to use "this" in both the main and other thread? Can't do that. You need to post some more code.

Comment: @HotLicks I have two logs one for the Web Service and another for the client that has spawns the threads. The main class is waiting and then one thread finishes and notifies the main class, what happens once the main class is not waiting anymore but another thread finishes and calls notify? Does the notify just get unheard and everything continues normally?

Comment: @edharned -- Why can you not have the same object in both threads?

Comment: As I said, if the notify is done with no waitor, the notify falls on the floor -- it's lost.  It doesn't work like a semaphore, in that regard.

Comment: @edharned "this" is the main class. The threads have a class member variable that contains the main class instance and call the synchronized method in that class.  The main class calls the wait method in the the class, and the threads call the notify method in the main class.

Comment: @maasg This is for work, it is going to be moved into production once I finish testing and fixing issues like this. The reason I am using wait and notify is so the main class does not take up CPU usage when it really does not need to be used until after a thread is done.

Comment: You don't use wait() correctly. Read its javadoc. There should be a loop, and a condition. Or even better, you shouldn't use wait at all, and use a higher-lever synchronization mechanism instead.

Comment: Note that, generally speaking, you do not use wait/notify by obtaining the lock immediately before the operation.  Rather you hold it for the duration of your operation, then release it.

Comment: @JBNizet From reading the doc, I seem to be using it as intended. I wait on the current thread (main class) and call the notify for that class when a thread is done.

Comment: BTW you should always put wait inside while loop

Comment: @user1750090: You don't have any condition, and you don't have any loop. The doc says: *As in the one argument version, interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop*. Read the doc again, as well as the doc of `wait(timeout)`

Comment: @user1750090 -- There are several things wrong with the way you're doing it.  Wait/notify is intended to be used with locks, but you're not really using locks (for any worthwhile purpose).  For your purposes a semaphore is far better.

Comment: @user1750090 considering this code is for production, I've proposed an answer using a robust concurrency facility.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest moving from the tricky wait/notify to one of the higher-level concurrency facilities in the Java platform.  The [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) probably offers the functionality you require out of the box.  ([CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) could also be used, but it's more plumbing)
Let's try to sketch an example using your code as template:

```
ExecutorService execSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);

while (true) {

    // Removed the code here, it was just calling a web service to get a list of companies
    List<FileProcessingTask> tasks = new ArrayList<FileProcessingTask>();
    for (Company comp:companyList) {
        tasks.add(new FileProcessingTask(comp));
    }
    List<Future<FileProcessingTask>> results = execSvc.invokeAll(tasks); // This call will block until all tasks are executed.
    //foreach Future<FileProcessingTask> in results: check result
}

class FileProcessingTask implements Callable<FileResult> {  // just like runnable but you can return a value -> very useful to gather results after the multi-threaded execution
    FileResult call() {...}
}
```

------- edit after comments ------

If your `getCompanies()` call can give you all companies at once, and there's no requirement to check that list continuously while processing, you could simplify the process by creating all work items first and submit them to the executor service all at once.

```
List<FileProcessingTask> tasks = new ArrayList<FileProcessingTask>();
    for (Company comp:companyList) {
        tasks.add(new FileProcessingTask(comp));
    }
```

The important thing to understand is that the executorService will use the provided collection as an internal queue of tasks to execute. It takes the first task, gives it to a thread of the pool, gathers the result, places the result in the result collection and then takes the next task in the queue.

If you don't have a producer/consumer scenario (cfr comments), where new work is produced at the same time that task are executed (consumed), then, this approach should be sufficient to parallelize the processing work among a number of threads in a simple way.

If you have additional requirements why the lookup of new work should happen interleaved from the processing of the work, you should make it clear in the question.

Comment: With this solution, I do not want to wait for all threads to finish because one thread could take for example 10 seconds while another could take 3 minutes depending on how many files to process.

Comment: @user1750090 I see. What's the role of waking up the main thread then? To find more work to do and start a new thread?  Do you have something like a thread is looking for work to do while multiple thread are processing that work?

Comment: The role of waking up the main thread is to create more threads when one is finished. Basically it will create a thread per company to process files and when a company is done then it will go back to the main thread and create another company thread to process. No I do not have a thread that is looking for work while multiple threads are processing the work. The only threads I have is the main thread that spawns the company threads and the company threads to do the file processing.

Comment: My advice would be to separate threads for work-to-be-done. The code above will work for any number of companies you would like to process. Imagine you have 40 companies to process: You create a `FileProcessingTask` for each company and submit it to the executor pool. The pool has `n` execution threads. Each time a task is finished, the executor will take the next task and execute it until all tasks are done. There's no need to "go back" to creating more threads every time one is finished (which is not interesting from performance perspective). I still believe above solution fulfills your need